# Angularjs JSON post/get methods in services

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, http-post

I need to implement multiple post/get methods in service/factory for pulling resources on remote server like [http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users](http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com) and listing, adding and removing them from table. I'm able to pull data and add data to server with get/post. Code for removing table row is not working. I'm doing all this with controller and with deprecated code :/ All other sollutions for using multiple methods in factory [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36655564/angular-have-multiple-functions-in-one-service), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17160771/angularjs-a-service-that-serves-multiple-resource-urls-data-sources), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25163559/correct-way-to-make-a-factory-module-in-angularjs/25164204#25164204), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21821150/can-i-have-multiple-functions-in-my-angularjs-factory) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33393436/angularjs-best-practice-factory-with-multiple-methods) don't work for me or I'm missing something. Here's my code:
HTML:

```js
app.factory('userservice', ['$http', function($http) { 
  return $http.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users') 
            .success(function(data) { 
            console.log(data);
              return data; 
            }) 
            .error(function(err) { 
            console.log(err);
              return err; 
            }); 
}]);
```

```html
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
      <head>
    <!--     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link href="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" /> -->
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        
        <!-- Include the AngularJS library -->
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular.min.js"></script>
      </head>
      <body ng-app="MailApp">
    
        <div class="main" ng-controller="MainController">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="forecast">
                  <table class="table table-bordered table table-hover">
                          <tr>
                           <th class="info" rowspan="2">ID</th>
                           <th class="info" rowspan="2">Name</th>
                           <th class="info" rowspan="2">User Name</th>
                           <th class="info" rowspan="2">Email</th>
                           <th class="info" colspan="3">Address</th>              
                          </tr>
    
                        <tr>
                           <th class="info" >Street</th>
                           <th class="info">Suite</th>
                           <th class="info">City</th>
                        </tr>
    
                        <tr ng-repeat="user in users">
                           <td>{{ user.id }}
                           <button data-ng-click="removeUser($index)">Remove</button>
                           <button data-ng-click="removePost()">Remove row</button>
                           </td>
                           <td>{{ user.name }}</td>
                           <td>{{ user.username }}</td>
                           <td>{{ user.email }}</td>
                           <td>{{ user.address.street }}</td>
                           <td>{{ user.address.suite }}</td>
                           <td>{{ user.address.city }}</td>
                        </tr>
                  </table>
    
                  <table class="table table-bordered table table-hover">
                        <tr>
                           <td><input type="text" ng-model="newPost.id" placeholder="User id"></td>
                           <td><input type="text" ng-model="newPost.name" placeholder="User name"></td>
                           <td><input type="text" ng-model="newPost.username" placeholder="User username"></td>
                           <td><input type="text" ng-model="newPost.email" placeholder="User email"></td>
                           <td><input type="text" ng-model="newPost.address.street" placeholder="User street"></td>
                           <td><input type="text" ng-model="newPost.address.suite" placeholder="User suite"></td>
                           <td><input type="text" ng-model="newPost.address.city" placeholder="User city"></td>
                        </tr>
                  </table>
                <button ng-click="addUser()">Add user</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    
        <!-- Modules -->
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    
        <!-- Controllers -->
        <script src="js/controllers/MainController.js"></script>
    
        <!-- Services -->
        <script src="js/services/userservice.js"></script>
    
        <!-- Directives -->
    
    
      </body>
    </html>
```

```js
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', 'userservice',  '$http',  function($scope, userservice, $http) { 
        $scope.users = []; 
        userservice.success(function(data) { 
        $scope.users = data;
      });
    
    $scope.addUser = function(){
      $http.post("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users",{
        id: $scope.newPost.id,
        name: $scope.newPost.name,
        username: $scope.newPost.username,
        email: $scope.newPost.email,
        address: 
        {
                street : $scope.newPost.address.street,
                suite : $scope.newPost.address.suite,
                city : $scope.newPost.address.city
        }
      })
    
      .success(function(data, status, headers, config){
        console.log(data);
        $scope.users.push($scope.newPost);
        $scope.newPost = {};
      })
      .error(function(error, status, headers, config){
        console.log(error);
      });
    }
    
    //simple remove array remove function 
    $scope.removeUser = function(index)
    {
        $scope.users.splice(index, 1);
    }
      //not working properly localy - raised issue on stack
      $scope.removePost = function () {
                var data = 
                {
                  id: $scope.newPost.id
                } 
                //Error: $scope.newPost is undefined
                //forwarding paramaeters directly or with pulling them with $routeParams and index 'id'
                $http.delete('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/' + data)
                .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    $scope.ServerResponse = data;
                })
                  .error(function (data, status, header) {
                    $scope.ServerResponse = htmlDecode("Data: " + data +
                        "\n\n\n\nstatus: " + status +
                        "\n\n\n\nheaders: " + header +
                        "\n\n\n\nconfig: " + config);
                });
            };
    }]);
```

Comment: There's an awful lot of code here - which part of the code is it that you're actually having a problem with?

Comment: I'm  trying to move code for removing/adding user from controller to factory but any ot the mentioned solutions on links don't work. I need three methods in factory get for listing users, post for adding user and deleting user. I just can't find slution how to implement those three methods in factor and then call them in controller.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you didn't define in your app.js your module. `var app = angular.module('MailApp',[])`. Can you show your app.js angular code?

Comment: There is only one line of code and i don't think that is a problem: var app = angular.module('MailApp', []);